# Page Will not redirect

Tags: visualforce, pagereference

I have a `commandbutton` on a VF page that calls a method in the controller that should redirect to a new `pagereference`. When I select a value from a `Selectcheckboxes` control, the page will not redirect and it appears that the method that should be called from the `commandbutton` is never invoked. I tried debugging, but none of my debugs show in the log. I also tried disabling development mode. No luck.

```
public PageReference toResultsPage()
{
    //do stuff
    PageReference page = new PageReference(
        'https://c.cs51.visual.force.com/apex/SearchResults?searchString='+searchStringATLEAST+'&searchStringALL='+searchStringALL+'&searchStringEXACT='+searchstringEXACT+'&queryString='+contentsearchquery
    );
    return page.setredirect(false);  
}
```

And the VF part:

```
<div class="col-md-12">  
    <div class="form-group text-center">  
        <apex:commandButton value="Enhanced Search" action="{!toResultsPage}" id="submit-search" styleClass="btn btn-primary gradient"/>      
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code which does the redirection please ?

Comment: Just added the method in the page controller. This works if fileFilters is empty, but fails if I select any of the checkboxes associated with filetypefilters

Comment: Please also post the markup for your `commandButton`.

Comment: do you see any required field on your vf page ?

Comment: There are no required fields on my page, but I do think I'm having an issue with validation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, I think the debug log was important because non of the debugs I had placed in my code were showing up in the log, which would lead me to believe that my method never fired, which might give someone a clue as to what the problem is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't initialize the list returned by the checkboxes control. This line:  filetypefilter=new list(); in the page constructor was not present in my original code and was causing the method called by the commandButton to fail, without an error. Also, if no values were selected from the list the method would fire, sending an email with no values. I could then make selections from the list and they would show in the email.

```
<apex:page controller="debugpage">  
<apex:form >
    <div class="col-md-4">           
        <h4>Refine by Document Type</h4>
        <apex:outputPanel id="files">
            <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!fileTypeFilter}"  layout="pageDirection">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!filelist}"/>
            </apex:selectCheckboxes>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>  
    <apex:commandButton Action="{!MethodName}" value="Emailresult"/>  
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>  

public with sharing class debugpage {

public list<selectoption> fileList{get;set;}//list to populate document type boolean list
public list<string> fileTypeFilter{get;set;}//list returned from filetype filter

public debugpage(){

    filetypefilter=new list<string>();
    filelist=new list<selectoption>();
    list<AggregateResult> extensionList=new list<AggregateResult>();//initialize list for file_type_families__c
    extensionlist=[select  extension_family__c from file_type_family__c group by extension_family__c]; //query for file type families       
    for(aggregateResult ar:extensionlist){//for each record returned in query for file type families add to filelist as a selectoption
        fileList.add(new SelectOption((string)ar.get('Extension_Family__c'),(string)ar.get('Extension_Family__c') ));
    }
}
public PageReference MethodName() {

List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'name@something.com'};

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();  
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
system.debug(toAddresses);
mail.setReplyTo('Noreply@systemmessage.com');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('System Automated Message');
mail.setSubject('What got Selected');

String body = 'settings ';
For (String i : FileTypeFilter){
    Body+= 'Line '+i;
}
mail.setHtmlBody(body);
mails.add(mail);
System.debug(body);
System.debug(mails);
Messaging.sendEmail(mails);


    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `PageReference` to cause a redirect, don't call `setRedirect(false)`. The default value is `true`.

Aside from this correction, you should construct your `PageReference` in such a way that it will work across all environments.

```
PageReference redirect = Page.SearchResults;
redirect.getParameters().put(searchString, someValue);
// etc.
return redirect;
```

Comment: the page will go to the requested page whether redirect is true or false. It's set to false because I want to maintain the state of the page. The page that I'm redirecting to will use the same controller.